# Pandas, I want to take the column of another table, and for each value of that column track it by every month in another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

super noob question here. So say I have two tables. One restaurant table, and the other inventory data. For each item id, I want to be able to track it in the restaurant table. So for id 1, 2, 3, I can track January along with capacity, then 1,2,3 again for February, etc. What's the best way to go about it in pandas since there's nothing really to merge on?

| Date | Inventory Capacity |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 25 |
| 02-02-2020 | 30 |
| 03- 03- 2020 | 35 |

| Item id | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 28 |

My expected output is something like this

Restaurant_inventory

| Date | Item id | amount | Inventory Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 1 | 15 | 25 |
| 01-01-2020 | 2 | 20 | 25 |
| 01-01-2020 | 3 | 28 | 25 |
| 02-02-2020 | 1 | 15 | 30 |
| 02-02-2020 | 2 | 20 | 30 |
| 02-02-2020 | 3 | 28 | 30 |
| 03-03-2020 | 1 | 15 | 35 |
| 03-03-2020 | 2 | 20 | 35 |
| 03-03-2020 | 3 | 28 | 35 |

Comment: can you post your expected output from the given df's?

Comment: how will you know item 1's capacity? How will it differ from item 2's? If there's no id column in the capacity table

Comment: Just added my expected output

Answer (score 0):

Merge them on cross join by using `pd.merge`

```
pd.merge(df, df2, how='cross')
```